# how to find oracle listener port in linux

Tags: java, linux, oracle11g

I have Oracle 11.2.0 installed in my Linux system, on which we are running one tool(developed in java), which needs as an input the port number where the oracle listener is running.

Is there any way to get the port number.

Comment: Start with the default: 1521.  See if "netstat -a" will show you LISTENING on that port #.  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/netstat-command-examples/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can typically see the port number you need in `listener.ora`:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DS-1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

To find you listener.ora, you can use eg

```
find . -type f -name listener.ora
```

Comment: I ran the command got many .ora files, in one of the files port was updated, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in listener.ora located at $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin folder.
or 
You can see lists of ports configured in portlist.ini located at $ORACLE_HOME/install folder

Answer (score 1):

From the command prompt you can use `lsnrctl status`, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/lsnrctl.htm#NETRF129) is the relevant documentation.

You can also use the Oracle Enterprise Manager web interface under `General -> Listener`.

Comment: I had tried this, its giving the following error,LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 16-JUL-2013 07:46:44

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

Comment: That means that the listener is not running and you need to start it with `lsnrctl start`.

Comment: The listener is already running, because I am able to login to the oracle using sqlplus.

Comment: You are able to login despite the listener being stopped because local connections to the database do not require a listener.